# Редактировать элемент двумерного вектора через указатель

Tags: c++, vector

Есть функция, возвращающая значение из указателя на двумерный массив:

```
int func(std::vector<std::vector<int>>* field)
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 3;
    int from_field = (field->at(x)).at(y);
    return from_field;
}
```

Как записать в field[x][y] новое значение внутри этой функции?

Comment: `(field->at(x)).at(y) = new_value;`?

Comment: оу, думал at не дает редактировать, спасибо)

Comment: А ещё лучше передавать вектор по ссылке `std::vector<std::vector<int>>& field` и тогда можно будет писать `field.at(x).at(y) = new_value;`. (Или даже `field[x][y] = new_value;`, но это без проверки выхода за границы вектора.)

Comment: А еще лучше (быстрее), если не надо проверять значения индексов, не выходят ли они за границы диапазонов, просто `(*field)[x][y]`